# How to output table serial numbers in vertical format using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, html

I have the following piece of code to output the student data in HTML table with serial number in vertical format, but I can't understand the logic where I would use the while loop. The desired output show in images
[image]

```
<?php
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `students` WHERE student_status = 'active' ");

$col = 4;  //number of desired columns 
$row = 5;  //number of desired rows
$output = '';
$output .='<table>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    for($i = 1; $i<$row+1; $i++){
        $output .='<tr>';
        for($c = 0; $c<$col; $c++){
            $output .='<td>'.($i + ($c*$row)).'</td>';
            $output .='<td>Here i need the student name fetch from DB</td>';
        }
        $output .='</tr>';
    }
}

$output .='</table>';
echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want from the loop, including the result set from the query?

Comment: @Sherif I want to output the data in 5 columns and 20 rows with just student_name value

Comment: @Sherif the desired output shows in attached image

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - _your_ "urgent" isn't really much of _our_ problem.

Comment: This would probably be easiest, if you fetched all your records into a numerically indexed array first. Then you can use the the number you are calculating there (minus 1), to directly address the corresponding record in your result set (if that exists, your query might have returned less records than would actually be needed to fill all cells - so _check_ first, before you try to access a record under a specific number.)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
        $col = 4;  //number of desired columns 
        $row = 20;  //number of desired rows
        $table_col=array();
        $output='<table border=1>';
        for($i = 1; $i<$row+1; $i++){
            $table_columns='';
             $output.="<tr>";
            for($c = 0; $c<$col; $c++){
                $table_columns .='<td>'.($i + ($c*$row)).'</td>';
                $table_columns .='<td>Here i need the student name fetch from DB</td>';
                
            }
            $output.=$table_columns;
             $output.="</tr>";
        }
        $output.='<table>';
       
        
        echo $output;
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the table will be 20x5 then another option is to put the results into an array.

```
$columns = array();
$col = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $columns[$col][] = $row['student_name'];
    $col++;

    if($col>=5){ $col = 1; }
}

//now to print the table using the indexing to calculate number
$output = '<table>';
foreach($columns as $rowNum=>$row){
    $output .= '<tr>';
    foreach($row as $i=>$student_name){
        $output .='<td>'.(($rowNum+1)+($i*5)).'</td>';
        $output .='<td>'.$student_name.'</td>';
    }
    $output .= '</tr>';
}

$output .='</table>';
echo $output;
```